# Pandas MemoryError with read_sql_query

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, memory

I am trying to read 2.7 million rows into Pandas Dataframe but running into memory issues (I guess). The strange part is when I monitor the RAM usage on the server python uses maximum 1.5 GB of the free 8 GB (Total RAM on the server is 16 GB).On the same setup, it can read up to a million rows easily.

What could be wrong here? Since it not using all the free memory and runs fine for less number of rows, could it be that python is limited for memory somehow?

Below is the code and some info about the setup;
Anaconda 1.4.3 with Python 2.7 (32 bit)
Windows Server with one Xeon processor and 16 GB RAM
SQL server on same machine limited to 4 GB RAM.

The Code:

```
def ingest_sql(connection, nrows, alldata,refresh=False):
"""Ingests the SQL query related to the data_flag.
:param connection:
:param nrows: number of rows
:param Refresh:
:return: data frame to read data into.
"""

df = []
print 'alldata:',alldata

if alldata == 'True':
    print "Reading All Data"

    print 'Select te.evtdescr, te.Ref_Badge_ID, te.Ref_Reader_ID, tr.SITE_ID AS SiteID, tb.id AS badgeid, te.event_time_utc, te.empid, te.cardnum, te.eventid, tp.ID AS personid, tp.NAME, tb.BADGENO '+ \
          'FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY te INNER JOIN TBL_Badges tb ON te.Ref_Badge_ID = tb.ID ' + \
          'INNER JOIN TBL_PERSONS tp ON tb.PERSONID = tp.ID ' + \
          'INNER JOIN TBL_READERS tr ON te.Ref_Reader_ID = tr.ID ' + \
          'WHERE empid>0 AND eventid<2 AND ' + \
          'Ref_Badge_ID IS NOT NULL and ' + \
          'Ref_Reader_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY event_time_utc',

    df = pd.read_sql_query('Select te.evtdescr, te.Ref_Badge_ID, te.Ref_Reader_ID, tr.SITE_ID AS SiteID, tb.id AS badgeid, te.event_time_utc, te.empid, te.cardnum, te.eventid, tp.ID AS personid, tp.NAME, tb.BADGENO '+
                            'FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY te INNER JOIN TBL_Badges tb ON te.Ref_Badge_ID = tb.ID ' +
                            'INNER JOIN TBL_PERSONS tp ON tb.PERSONID = tp.ID '+
                            'INNER JOIN TBL_READERS tr ON te.Ref_Reader_ID = tr.ID '+
                            'WHERE empid>0 AND eventid<2 AND '+
                            'Ref_Badge_ID IS NOT NULL and '+
                            'Ref_Reader_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY event_time_utc',
                           connection)
else:
    print 'Alldata is False'
    print "Reading only "+ nrows + " rows"
    print 'Select top ' + str(nrows) + ' te.evtdescr, te.Ref_Badge_ID, te.Ref_Reader_ID, tr.SITE_ID AS SiteID, tb.id AS badgeid, te.event_time_utc, te.empid, te.cardnum, te.eventid, tp.ID AS personid, tp.NAME, tb.BADGENO '+ \
          'FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY te INNER JOIN TBL_Badges tb ON te.Ref_Badge_ID = tb.ID ' +\
            'INNER JOIN TBL_PERSONS tp ON tb.PERSONID = tp.ID ' +\
            'INNER JOIN TBL_READERS tr ON te.Ref_Reader_ID = tr.ID ' +\
            'WHERE empid>0 AND eventid<2 AND ' +\
            'Ref_Badge_ID IS NOT NULL and ' +\
            'Ref_Reader_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY event_time_utc',

    df = pd.read_sql_query('Select top '+ str(nrows) +\
                           ' te.evtdescr, te.Ref_Badge_ID, te.Ref_Reader_ID, tr.SITE_ID AS SiteID, tb.id AS badgeid, te.event_time_utc, te.empid, te.cardnum, te.eventid, tp.ID AS personid, tp.NAME, tb.BADGENO '+
                           'FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY te INNER JOIN TBL_Badges tb ON te.Ref_Badge_ID = tb.ID ' +
                           'INNER JOIN TBL_PERSONS tp ON tb.PERSONID = tp.ID ' +
                           'INNER JOIN TBL_READERS tr ON te.Ref_Reader_ID = tr.ID ' +
                           'WHERE empid>0 AND eventid<2 AND ' +
                           'Ref_Badge_ID IS NOT NULL and ' +
                           'Ref_Reader_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY event_time_utc',
                          connection)

return df
```

Here is the Error:

```
  global start_time
" the MASTER GLUE FUNCTION
pandas imported
all external packages imporated
WIC: future imported
banana phone
DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.180.10.67;DATABASE=SAFEANALYTICS;UID=safeapp;PWD=safeapp
winter is coming imported
TBL_READERS
ID
Starting:
full_run: True
date_flag is False
alldata: True
Reading All Data
Select te.evtdescr, te.Ref_Badge_ID, te.Ref_Reader_ID, tr.SITE_ID AS SiteID, tb.id AS badgeid, te.event_time_utc, te.empid, te.cardnum, te.eventid, tp.ID AS personid, tp.NAME, tb.BADGENO FROM TBL_EVENTS_HISTORY te INNER JOIN TBL_Badges tb ON te.Ref_Badge_ID = tb.ID INNER JOIN TBL_PERSONS tp ON tb.PERSONID = tp.ID INNER JOIN TBL_READERS tr ON te.Ref_Reader_ID = tr.ID WHERE empid>0 AND eventid<2 AND Ref_Badge_ID IS NOT NULL and Ref_Reader_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY event_time_utc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Transfer\Project\VARYS_DRS_02232017\Calculate_Risk.py", line 141, in <module>
    make_risk_tables(dev=args.dev,nrows_0=args.nrows_0,nrows=args.nrows,dataflag=args.data_flag,all_data=True)
  File "C:\Transfer\Project\VARYS_DRS_02232017\Calculate_Risk.py", line 35, in make_risk_tables
    WINterIsComing_with_devid.WinVarys(nrows=nrows_0,data_flag=dataflag,refresh=dev,alldata=all_data)
  File "C:\Transfer\Project\VARYS_DRS_02232017\WINterIsComing_with_devid.py", line 151, in WinVarys
    df = read_columns_into_df(data_flag, df)
  File "C:\Transfer\Project\VARYS_DRS_02232017\WINterIsComing_with_devid.py", line 112, in read_columns_into_df
    df=df.drop_duplicates()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3138, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3188, in duplicated
    labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3177, in f
    _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 313, in factorize
    labels = table.get_labels(vals, uniques, 0, na_sentinel, True)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 839, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels (pandas\hashtable.c:15395)
MemoryError
[Finished in 58.3s]
```

Comment: try 64-bit python

Comment: I am using Cython in other part of project, that needs 32 bit :(

Comment: cython doesn't require 32-bit python

Comment: Well the 64 bit does seem to work, but I am trying it in a slightly different env. Will update once I am able to run successfully on the env that was causing issue.                                                                        But my question is if you ok to answer, why can't 32 bit python 2.7 process just 1GB (2.7 million rows) of Data? This is relatively smaller chuck vs what I have heard python is capable of.

Comment: it probably has to allocate more memory than that before it can fit it into the final structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Paul suggested upgrading python 2.7 32-bit to 64-bit worked. I am not completely sure why it worked, but compiling Cython code with 64-bit python is difficult with Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python. So had to remove the Cython code.